# How to find rows IDs that a value exists in any of column in R and then put Exists to a new dataframe

Tags: r

want to find to which rows but in any column,there is a dataframe

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `rowSums` on a logical matrix created with `==`, then convert it to a logical vector with `> 0`, wrap with `which` to return the row index where atleast one column have 'citrus fruit' value.  Use that index to change the value in 'newcol' of the dataset 'groc' to 'exists'

```
i1 <- which(rowSums(A == 'citrus fruit') > 0)
groc$newcol[i1] <- 'exists'
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
A <- data.frame(col1 = c('citrus fruit', 'a', 'b'), col2 = c('a', 'b',
       'citrus fruit'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
groc <- data.frame(value = rnorm(3))
```